# RxJS indexOfQuizId undefined in console

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I've started refactoring my code to work with Angular Observables and I'm using the Observable 'of' for the quizzes$ array, but I'm stuck at getting indexOfQuizId working, specifically with findIndex. I am getting an undefined value for this.indexOfQuizId in the console, not sure what I'm doing wrong... Please could you see my code below (in getIndexOfQuizId()) and help to get it to work. Thank you!

In quiz.ts:
`export const getQuizzes$: Observable<Quiz[]> = of([quiz data inside array]);`

In quiz.service.ts:

```
export class QuizService {
  quizzes$: Observable<Quiz[]>;
  ...

  constructor(...) {
    this.quizzes$ = getQuizzes$;
    ...
  }

  getQuizzes(): Observable<Quiz[]> {
    return this.quizzes$;
  }

  getIndexOfQuizId() {
    const index = this.getQuizzes().pipe(map(quizzes => {
        this.indexOfQuizId = quizzes.findIndex((elem) => elem.quizId === this.quizId);
      })).subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
        console.log('IOQID: ', this.indexOfQuizId);
      });
  }
```

In quiz.component.html, I'm using this.indexOfQuizId to access the quizzes$ array object like this:

`this.totalQuestions = this.quizzes$[this.quizService.indexOfQuizId].questions.length;`

Comment: Use arrow function in callbacks to refer the `this` keyword to class member variables. Try: `quizzes.findIndex((elem, i, obs) => elem.quizId === this.quizId)`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code above to use an arrow function.

Comment: I'm getting undefined value for this.quizId. In the constructor I have this.quizId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['quizId']; and my route looks like: { path: 'question/:quizId/:questionIndex', component: QuizComponent },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an undefined for this line `console.log('IOQID: ', this.indexOfQuizId);` and it's quite right.

As you may know, the `subscribe` is asynchronous, that means that the next line (`console.log('IOQID: ', this.indexOfQuizId);`) is called before you set any value into this.indexOfQuizId since the `map` will be called eventually.

Try to move the console.log into the `subscribe` like this:

```
  getIndexOfQuizId() {
    const index = this.getQuizzes().pipe(map(quizzes => {
      this.indexOfQuizId = quizzes.findIndex(function(elem, i, obs) { return elem => elem.quizId === this.quizId; });
    })).subscribe(x => {
       console.log(x);
       console.log('IOQID: ', this.indexOfQuizId);
    });
   }
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting value of 0 for IOQID now in the console, no matter which quiz I try.

Comment: What's the value of this.quizId ? Maybe it's always 0 or your quizzes array don't have the  id that you're checking or the quizzes array is empty

Comment: I checked, this.quizId is null in the console. I have defined this.quizId in the constructor this.quizId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('quizId');

Comment: And you call the url like http://localhost:4221/quizz?quizId=123 ?

Comment: I'm getting a value of -1 for IOQID now. I changed the code to use arrow function: const index = this.getQuizzes().pipe(map(quizzes => {
        this.indexOfQuizId = quizzes.findIndex((elem, i, obs) => elem.quizId === this.quizId );
      })).subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
        console.log('IOQID: ', this.indexOfQuizId);
      });
    console.log('quizId: ', this.quizId);

Comment: URL looks like: http://localhost:4200/quiz/question/dependency-injection/1

Comment: I do think that you retrieve the param in the wrong way. You must do something like this: this.quizId= route.snapshot.params["quizId"]; and in  your route: { path: "dependency-injection/:quizId", component: quizzComponent },

Comment: My route looks like: { path: 'question/:quizId/:questionIndex', component: QuizComponent }, and I tried changed this.quizId to your code but still getting undefined for quizId and -1 for IOQID

Comment: the name after the ":" is the one you must use. Hence  this.quizId= route.snapshot.params["questionIndex"];

Comment: I tried changing to questionIndex, but still am getting the same values. Please could you see my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app

Comment: You code is rather complex. Try first getting the parameters from the route by tracing it of logging it into the console. It's another question.